# How to link and view PDF in browser with HTML/Angular project?

Tags: html, css, angular, visual-studio-2017

I want to link my resume on my personal website. I'm using the Angular template with Visual Studio 2017.

I have my PDF inside my project directory.

/components/navmenu/resume.pdf

/components/navmenu/navmenu.component.html

/components/navmenu/navmenu.component.css

/components/navmenu/navmenu.component.ts

Inside navmenu.component.html, I have

```
<a href="resume.pdf">Resume</a>
```

I haven't published the project to a server. It is just running on Localhost. How do I view resume.pdf in browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double check your URL used in the anchor tag. Perhaps you could also consider creating a folder under the root of your angular project, say `contents` or something similar, where you can put your files in there. Then you just need to reference it like

```
<a href="/contents/resume.pdf">Resume</a>
```

Comment: I have tried putting it in another folder with no success. When I try to open the link, I get an error saying "Unable to load pdf document". The url it's trying to access is file:///C:/Users/Name/AppData/Local/Temp/resume.pdf.

Comment: I got it working. Looks like I wasn't placing my PDF file in wwwroot. Thanks!